# How Can I get the same data different divs

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, article

How can I reach the text div? This is a website divs and I would like to get datas from different divs.
There are more article2 divs in the col... divs.
I need every text data. But my code don't working because i don't know how to reach the different divs with same time(col_6...,col_3... divs).

My code:

```
article_title = div.find('div', attrs={'class':'article2'}).find('div', attrs={'class':'text'}).find('h1')
```

The site code:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col_6 ct_12 cd_12 cm_12">
            <a href="https://kronikaonline.ro/erdelyi-hirek/uralkodasanak-helyszinen-a-gyulafehervari-varban-allitanak-emleket-bethlen-gabor-erdelyi-fejedelemnek">
            <div class="article2" style="padding-top:0px;">
               <div class="text">
               <h1>TITLE</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col_3 ct_12 cd_12 cm_12">
        </div>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `find_all()` or `css selectors` to select all your articles and iterate the `ResultSet` to get all information you like to scrape:

```
for a in soup.select('div.article2'):
    print(f"title: {a.h1.text}")
    print(f"url: {a.find_previous('a').get('href')}")
```

##### Example

Extract data and store in list of dicts:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div class="row">
        <div class="col_6 ct_12 cd_12 cm_12">
            <a href="url1">
            <div class="article2" style="padding-top:0px;">
               <div class="text">
               <h1>TITLE1</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col_6 ct_12 cd_12 cm_12">
            <a href="url2">
            <div class="article2" style="padding-top:0px;">
               <div class="text">
               <h1>TITLE2</h1>
               </div>
            </div>
            </a>
        </div>
   </div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

data = []

for a in soup.select('div.article2'):
    data.append({
        'title': a.h1.text,
        'url': a.find_previous('a').get('href')
    })

print(data)
```

###### Output

```
[{'title': 'TITLE1', 'url': 'url1'}, {'title': 'TITLE2', 'url': 'url2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use find_all instead of find to reach all the div

```
div.find_all("div")
```

It will return a list of all matching items.

https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=find_all#find-all

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the text for each h1 element of each article?

```
# Find all the h1 in the soup object
all_h1_title = div.find_all('h1')

# print each h1 text
for each_h1 in all_h1:
    print(each_h1.text)
```

More about find_all(): [https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:~:text=tree%2C%20such%20as-,find_all(),-%3A](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#:%7E:text=tree%2C%20such%20as-,find_all(),-%3A)